# How can I detect what room a user disconnected from?

Tags: flask-socketio

I have an application that I need to pass the room the current user has just disconnected from to the server. The user can be in multiple rooms via multiple tabs.

I can detect that the user has left this way but it does not seem to be able to have data passed with it:

```
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print(session['id'])
    print("user left " )
```

In my client end I have tried this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
     socket.emit('user_disconnect', {"channel": "{{symbol}}"});
 });
```

This emit never goes through to the server though. I am guessing the window closes or changes before this can get called? How can I pass data to the server on the disconnect event?

Comment: Have you tried calling the `rooms()` function inside your disconnect handler? That should give you the list of rooms your client is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured out a solution.

Utilizing `request.sid`, I can store the room name in a list along with this sid on the server-side join event.

```
@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
active_rooms.append(json.dumps({'room':data['channel'],'socket_id':str(request.sid)}))
```

When the disconnect event is triggered I can view this same `sid` and use it as a lookup in the list. The sid appears to be unique for each socket connection so multiple tabs will result in a new sid.